# Write a function that mirrors stack behavior, but with a queue...?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, stack, queue

I ran into this question on a mock interview and I am not sure I even understand what it's asking.  I am supposed to write a function that has a queue, but the properties of a stack?

Here is my basic implementation of a stack:

```
function Stack() {
  this._size = 0;
  this._storage = {};
}

Stack.prototype.push = function(data) {
  var size = this._size++

  this._storage[size] = data;
}

Stack.prototype.pop = function() {
    var size = this._size,
        deletedData;

    if (size) {
        deletedData = this._storage[size];

        delete this._storage[size];
        this._size--;

        return deletedData;
    }
};
```

And this is my implementation of queue:

```
function Queue() {
  this._newestIndex = 1;
  this._oldestIndex = 1;
  this._storage = {};
}

Queue.prototype.size = function() {
  console.log(this._newestIndex - this._oldestIndex);
}

Queue.prototype.enqueue = function(data) {
  this._storage[this._newestIndex] = data;
  this._newestIndex++;
}

Queue.prototype.dequeue = function() {
  var oldestIndex = this._oldestIndex;
  var newestIndex = this._newestIndex;
  var datatoDelete;


  if (newestIndex !== oldestIndex) {
    datatoDelete = this._storage[oldestIndex]
    delete this._storage[oldestIndex];
    this._oldestIndex++;

    return datatoDelete;

  }

}
```

How might I implement this in my example?

Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with using an Array for this?

Comment: We ask a question like this where work, but the answer requires the use of two queues...

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure I even understand what it's asking

Well, you need to create a stack using queue, i.e., you assume that you have been given queue data-structure and using the functions provided in the queue data-structures, you need to create a stack.

Therefore, the structure of your Stack code will look something like this:

```
function push(){
//code for push but using queue data-structures functions
}

function pop(){
//code for pop but using queue data-structures
}
```

Hint: 
1) By using a queue to create a stack, you have to make either "pop" or "push" operation expensive. By expensive I mean, now either pop operation will not be in o(1) or push operation will not be in O(1).

2) You would need two queue data-structures to implement stack.